# Firestore update nested data

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i am stuck with a problem with firebase (with Vue). I want to add the user id to a specific map (yes, maybe or no) when the user presses a specific button. But Im having trouble add/update the data because its nested.
Here is my data structure in Firestore

[image: firestore data structure]

I want to add the user id in a map, something like this:

```
dates: {
    [
        0: {
            yes: [userId1, userId2]
        }
    ]
}
```

Does anyone can help me pushing the user ids into the arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, right now it is not possible to update a specific element of the array. You can add new items or remove them - look [here](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/samples/firestore-data-set-array-operations#code-sample). But I would consider a little change in the approach and create a collection called *dates* in which you can define documents, which will contain **yes**, **no**, **maybe** arrays, which can be easily updated - in the way mentioned before.